# calling a getJSON function from a button - not working in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: asynchronous, mediawiki, getjson

I am trying to access the Wikimedia API and display ten results.  I have written a function that accesses the API and works on its own.
However, when I try to integrate a Search button to call that function and pass the search string to the function nothing happens in Chrome or Firefox.
(oddly though when I use the snippet function within stackoverflow it works fine!) 
I'm wondering why my code doesn't work in the browser - could this have something to do with synchronous/asynchronous behavior and if so what is happening?

I'd really appreciate some insight into what is going on...

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {

//  Initialize the Global Variables

var api = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?&format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=";
var searchTitle = "";
var searchString = "";


$('#submit').click( function() {
 searchTitle = $("input:text").val();
 searchString = api + searchTitle;
 getWiki(searchString); 
});

// the following function works if I call it statically outside of the button click  
// for example: getWiki(api + "giraffe");
// but it doesn't work if I call it dynamically from within the button.  Why?

function getWiki(val) {
 $.getJSON(val, function(json) {
     $.each(json.query.pages, function(prop, item) {
      var id = "#result" + item.index
         $(id).html(item.title + "<br>" + item.extract);
        });
 });
}

//  END Document Ready Function
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


<form class="form-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for..." required>
    <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit">
</form>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div id="result1"></div>
   <div id="result2"></div>
   <div id="result3"></div>
   <div id="result4"></div>
   <div id="result5"></div>
   <div id="result6"></div>
   <div id="result7"></div>
   <div id="result8"></div>
   <div id="result9"></div>
   <div id="result10"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: i'm not sure about this selector: `$("input:text")` try this instead: $("input[type='text']")

Comment: the $("input:text") works.  
If I add console.log(searchString) to the button function it displays the input text correctly.  
The issue isn't in the button functionality but  instead when the getWiki(searchString) function is called nothing happens.

Comment: if the function works by itself then the function is not the issue but rather the way you're calling it. debugging 101. look elsewhere for the issue. not sure why that selector is working, there is nothing in the jQuery docs to imply that is a valid selector.

Comment: assuming it's a submit button, you may need to prevent the form from submitting. `$('#submit').click( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Comment: Thanks. Silly me. Here I was thinking it was something complicated.  it's the form that's not working.

Comment: woot. i was helpful.